# Do I need multiple viewHolders for ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-adapter

Am I using this viewholder wrong?  I'm getting an NPE on line 165.  Is there an obvious reason why that I'm missing?  Do I need a group viewholder and a child viewholder if I'm using expandablelistview?  I marked line 165 to try to make it easier on the eyes.

Thanks a lot

my expandablelistview that's getting the NPE:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ContactNameItems> mListDataHeader;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> phoneNumberCheckStates;
    private ArrayList<String> selectedNumbers;

    private HashMap<String, List<ContactPhoneItems>> mListDataChild;

    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<ContactNameItems> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<ContactPhoneItems>> listDataChild,
            ArrayList<String> listOfNumbers) {

        mContext = context;
        mListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        mListDataChild = listDataChild;
        selectedNumbers = listOfNumbers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mListDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactNameItems getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String contactName = getGroup(groupPosition).getName();
        Bitmap contactImage = getGroup(groupPosition).getImage();

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_name_item, null);

            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            mViewHolder.mContactName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

            mViewHolder.mContactImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivContactPhoto);

            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {

            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (contactImage != null) {
            mViewHolder.mContactImage.setImageBitmap(contactImage);

        } else {
            mViewHolder.mContactImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_contact);
        }

        mViewHolder.mContactName.setText(contactName);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mListDataChild.get(mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getName())
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactPhoneItems getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mListDataChild.get(mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getName())
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String numberText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getNumber();
        String typeText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getPhoneType();

        final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_detail_item, null);

            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            mViewHolder.mPhoneNumber = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_phone_number);

            mViewHolder.mPhoneType = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_phone_type);

            mViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

        } else {

            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        mViewHolder.mPhoneNumber.setText(numberText);
        mViewHolder.mPhoneType.setText(typeText);

        phoneNumberCheckStates = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mListDataChild.size(); i++) {

            phoneNumberCheckStates.add(false);
        }

        if (phoneNumberCheckStates.get(childPosition)) {
            mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

/*this is line 165*/    if (mViewHolder.mCheckBox.isChecked()) {  /*this is line 165*/
                    phoneNumberCheckStates.set(childPosition, true);

                    selectedNumbers.add(mListDataChild
                            .get(mListDataHeader.get(mGroupPosition).getName())
                            .get(childPosition).getNumber());

                } else {
                    phoneNumberCheckStates.set(childPosition, false);

                    selectedNumbers.remove(mListDataChild
                            .get(mListDataHeader.get(mGroupPosition).getName())
                            .get(childPosition).getNumber());
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    public ArrayList<Boolean> getCheckedNumbers() {

        return phoneNumberCheckStates;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSelectedNumbers() {

        return selectedNumbers;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView mContactName;
        TextView mPhoneNumber;
        TextView mPhoneType;
        ImageView mContactImage;
        CheckBox mCheckBox;
    }
}
```

if it helps, here's the Log:

```
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at com.psesto.journeysend.contactpicker.MyExpandableListAdapter$1.onClick(MyExpandableListAdapter.java:165)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-25 04:34:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one `ViewHolder` reference in your `Adapter` for all your `Views`. This makes no sense because every View in the List has its own instance of the `ViewHolder` which you get by `View.getTag()`.

You could set an `int[]` with the positions you need as a Tag of `CheckBox`

```
    int[] positions = new int[2];
    positions[0] = childPosition;
    positions[1] = groupPosition;
    mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setTag(positions);
```

and in `onClick()`

```
    CheckBox box = (CheckBox) v;
    int[] posTag = (int[]) v.getTag();
```

Then you have the CheckBox for the state and the positions for the rest

Answer (score 6):

I accepted Towlie288's answer because it pointed me in the right direction.  Here's the code change that made everything work:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ContactNameItems> mListDataHeader;
    private ArrayList<String> selectedNumbers;

    private HashMap<String, List<ContactPhoneItems>> mListDataChild;

    private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
    private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<ContactNameItems> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<ContactPhoneItems>> listDataChild,
            ArrayList<String> listOfNumbers) {

        mContext = context;
        mListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        mListDataChild = listDataChild;
        selectedNumbers = listOfNumbers;

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mListDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactNameItems getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String contactName = getGroup(groupPosition).getName();
        Bitmap contactImage = getGroup(groupPosition).getImage();

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_name_item, null);

            groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();

            groupViewHolder.mContactName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

            groupViewHolder.mContactImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivContactPhoto);

            convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
        } else {

            groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (contactImage != null) {
            groupViewHolder.mContactImage.setImageBitmap(contactImage);

        } else {
            groupViewHolder.mContactImage
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.default_contact);
        }

        groupViewHolder.mContactName.setText(contactName);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mListDataChild.get(mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getName())
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactPhoneItems getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mListDataChild.get(mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getName())
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String numberText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getNumber();
        String typeText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getPhoneType();

        final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_detail_item, null);

            childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

            childViewHolder.mPhoneNumber = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_phone_number);

            childViewHolder.mPhoneType = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_phone_type);

            childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);

            convertView.setTag(childViewHolder);

        } else {

            childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        childViewHolder.mPhoneNumber.setText(numberText);
        childViewHolder.mPhoneType.setText(typeText);

        ContactPhoneItems cpi = getChild(mGroupPosition, childPosition);

        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setTag(cpi);
        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(cpi.getSelected());

        // for managing the state of the boolean
        // array according to the state of the
        // CheckBox

        childViewHolder.mCheckBox
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    String contactNumber = mListDataChild
                            .get(mListDataHeader.get(mGroupPosition).getName())
                            .get(childPosition).getNumber();

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();

                        if (isChecked) {

                            selectedNumbers.add(contactNumber);

                        } else {

                            selectedNumbers.remove(contactNumber);
                        }

                        getChild(mGroupPosition, childPosition).setSelected(isChecked);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSelectedNumbers() {

        return selectedNumbers;
    }

    public final class GroupViewHolder {

        TextView mContactName;
        ImageView mContactImage;
    }

    public final class ChildViewHolder {

        TextView mPhoneNumber;
        TextView mPhoneType;
        CheckBox mCheckBox;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            ContactPhoneItems c = (ContactPhoneItems) buttonView.getTag();
            c.setSelected(isChecked);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Sounds good with me. Just a side note: I noticed you used inflate(R.layout.contact_detail_item, null); instead of inflate(R.layout.contact_detail_item, parent, false); Later one seems to be a better option if I'm correctly informed.

Comment: By the way, your final int mGroupPosition is never used? Or do I miss something?

Comment: It is used, just do a search for it.  But with recyclerview, I consider this to be a little outdated.

Answer (score -1):

This happens if a `Child`'s view is reusing a `Group`'s view, also the `ViewHolder` of it. Obviously, it cannot find `mCheckBox` in line 165, because it has not been set.
Simply adding a flag in `ViewHolder`, to check whether it is a `Child`'s `ViewHolder` could solve your problem. No need to have two kinds of `ViewHolder` here.
Hope is helps

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean by adding a flag.  Sorry, self-taught here.  Learning as I go